# MySQL is not starting on Xampp Control Panel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, wamp

Error

```
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
1:47:20 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Log :

```
2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 2013-12-12 01:33:01 828 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size     is 
 DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with 

the           option ``innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal 
memory           allocator. 
2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows 
interlocked        functions  
2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
  2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
 2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
 2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 2013-12-12 01:33:01 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 2013-12-12 01:33:02 3204 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320    
  pages  , LSN=1625987 
2013-12-12 01:33:02 3204 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2013-12-12 01:33:02 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql
\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB

2013-12-12 01:33:02 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql     
\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB

2013-12-12 01:33:02 3204 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql
```

facing this error , WHY ?

Comment: May not solve your problem, but try doing Right Click -> Run As Administrator on `xampp-control.exe`, then try to start MySQL from that. I find that often works for me.

Comment: Is that all you have in your log file? I don't see it shutdown at the end. Actually, even your last line ends unexpectedly. Please paste more of your log file.

Comment: Hey, switch your ports to 8888, you've probably got Skype up or something that uses the same port

Comment: I agree with @BuddhistBeast. Your log will show the way, though. If it's not a port conflict, then you may have changed something in your MySQL config file that is keeping MySQL from starting.

Comment: I Already Did all of these thing that you guys are telling

Comment: Yes the log file is too large to paste here

Comment: Did you look at the Windows Event Viewer for message from MySQL??

Answer (score 0):

My friend! it seems somke other application is running on the same
    port number as the apache or mysql. The default port number of
    apache server is **80**. Accidentally Skype uses the same port number as
    the apache server. And maybe the default port number **3306** used by
    mysql server is also being used by some other application. In my
    case it was the wampp server which also has mysql server inbuilt
    into it.

### 1. Changing the Apache servers port number.

```
                         Now what you gonna so it change the default port numbers of both the apache server and the mysql server
manually. To change the port number of apache, u have to o into the
xampp folder in your installation directory(Mine was C drive). In
there the file location would be :
```

> C:\xampp\apache\conf

(Ur
    installation directory may as well be different). In there theres a
    CONF file/configuration file named **httpd.conf**. Open the file using
    any text editor and then try finding the number ***80*** manually or
    usiong a finder(**Ctrl + F** in notepad++ for ex.). You will find them
    at **#Listen *12.34.56.78:12* Listen *12*** and **ServerName localhost:*12***.
    In both these places replace the number 80 with a well chosen number
    and remember that the number at all the places should be the same,
    and remember the number that you choose.

### 2.Changing the port number for MySql server

```
                         Now do the same thiong for Mysql server. It is located in
```

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin

named "my"(select and right click
    to view properties. Its an ini file). Open it with a text
    editor.Find ***3306*** and replace it with a well chosen and unique
    number at all the places(If u had changed the port number during
    installation or afterwards find that particular numbere and change
    it).

### 3.Starting the Apache server and testing it

Start the Apache server using the XMPP control panel and then test the apache local server by entering the url into the
    browser as you always did. But this time append localhost or
    127.0.0.1 with 12 seperated by a semicolon, For ex : ***localhost:25*** or ***127.0.0.1:25***, if your new port number is *25*. And I think you
    will be good to go. If u have any further problems, feel free to
    ask....